# want to access user friendly url

Tags: asp.net, url, umbraco

I have re-written URLs so that they are user friendly. I want to access user friendly URL that appears on address bar.

by using

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

, I get URL with query string parameters such as http://mydomain.com/default.aspx?id=3 .... but I want http://http://mydomain.com/default/3/ ... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Uri.AbsolutePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) not AbsoluteUri.

> The AbsolutePath property contains the path information that the
>   server uses to resolve requests for information. Typically this is the
>   path to the desired information on the server's file system, although
>   it also can indicate the application or script the server must run to
>   provide the information.
>
> The path information does not include the scheme, host name, or query
>   portion of the URI.

This would allow you to combine the Uri.Host with Uri.AbsolutePath such as:

```
Response.Write("http://" + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

For a web app this assumes you're on Port 80. If you can be on alternative ports you'll have to include a call to `Url.Port` as well.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Uri.AbsolutePath; is showing error.... its not possible to use this.... am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I assumed you were using .NET 4 since no specific version was tagged.

Comment: I am using this in Umbraco CMS . using this ........ "http://" + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath .. .does not get userfireldy url with parameters.... like http://mydomain.com/default/param/

Comment: @ghetal Try using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url (the property is URL, but the type is URI). Also, what language is your CMS using? I have never used it so I'm not sure how to give you a direct code block.